# Should I request permission App Tracking Transparency for Firebase Analytics in IOS Application?

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-analytics, apptrackingtransparency

Currently I use firebase analytics for collect user events or user activities in my application. Should I request permission for App Tracking Transparency ?

Answer (score 1):

> You must use the AppTrackingTransparency framework if your app
> collects data about end users and shares it with other companies for
> purposes of tracking across apps and web sites.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/apptrackingtransparency

Comment: Yes, but the question is whether Google is tracking users with it. I can't find any info from Google anywhere where they answer this question.

Answer (score 1):

From the firebase analytics docs:

> Analytics event logging, event reporting, and conversion measurement are
> unaffected, but attribution is impacted if IDFA is not accessible. To
> learn more about Google’s response to iOS 14, see our blog post.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/ios/supporting-ios-14#affected-firebase-integrations

Comment: hi the conversion measurement means the conversion from our google ad (no of install from our google ad post )

Answer (score 1):

**No**, from your description you're not tracking the user, and hence you don't need to request app tracking permission. But if you're still unsure, please edit your question to specify exactly what data you're collecting and what analytics you're using.

Are you only collecting information about what screens are visited and what buttons are pushed? If you're collecting this data to see what features users are using (and not using), and if you're not attempting to use this data to identify individual users, then you shouldn't need to ask permission to track.

However, you will need to specify the data collected and its use in the Privacy Nutrition Label for your app.

The WWDC video "Create Your Privacy Nutitrition Label" from 2022 provides info that I was looking for, and that may help you, too.

https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2022/10167/

If you're just collecting analytics about app usage, such as what screens users (in general) are clicking, then you need to disclose that in your Privacy Nutrition Label.

> Product Interaction covers data collected about the user's interactions inside the app, such as information about which screens people open.

See also
https://developer.apple.com/app-store/user-privacy-and-data-use/

> The following use cases are not considered tracking, and do not require user permission through the AppTrackingTransparency framework:

> When user or device data from your app is linked to third-party data solely on the user’s device and is not sent off the device in a way that can identify the user or device.